# df.drop_duplicates() does not work on dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not sure what the issue is but after I conducted a SQL join statement, I then created a dataframe with all my data. What I end up with is a dataframe with duplicates. Then, I applied `df.drop_duplicates()` but my dataframe does not take it at all and I get the same results. Here is a list of the dtypes I am using. May it have to do with that?

```
session id           int64
screens              int64
format              object
printer beacon      object
printed pages      float64
instant ink         object
printer             object
connection type     object
flow                object
app  id             object
new visits         float64
hits                 int64
seconds              int64
browser version     object
os version          object
device              object
resolution          object
country             object
dtype: object
```

This is an example of my result table: As you can see the first 3 rows are dups.

```
df.drop_duplicates()

Out[34]: 
                 session id  screens format printer beacon  printed pages  \
106038  9222306967988147151       36    pdf        Success            0.0   
106026  9222306967988147151       36    pdf        Success            0.0   
96108   9222306967988147151       36    pdf        Success            0.0   
288841  9221900072932373084       19      0        Success            0.0   
270720  9221453439142959638       17      0        Success            0.0
```

Please help as I am not sure what to do :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do `df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)` by default `inplace` is false in the `drop_duplicates()`. Having `inplace=True` will override your original dataframe.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

Comment: oh, how great! it worked magic! Do you have command to check if I have any dups remaining? Just to double check if the drop function really worked?

Comment: `df.duplicated()` should be able to achieve what you want. It returns the boolean values, True for duplicates, and false for non-duplicates. If there is no duplicates, all should be false. `df[df.duplicated()]` is what you want.

Comment: Aslo if my answer helped you, consider upvoting it. Thanks

Comment: @user2906838 the OP doesn't have enough reputation to upvote yet (Need > 15 reputation to upvote)